# ¿Como genero un código aleatorio que no se repita en Swift 3?

Tags: swift, swift2, swift3, random

Que tal necesito generar un código aleatorio en Swift sin que se repitan algo como esto:

x3q1iOpTcR

Cv3m5LuO21

He buscado pero solo encuentro como generar un numero random sin caracteres y he encontrado como crear un UUID

```
let uuid = NSUUID().UUIDString.lowercaseString

print(uuid)
```

> Salida:
>   68b696d7-320b-4402-a412-d9cee10fc6a3

Puedo utilizar este pero como lo limito a 10 caracteres y que se guarden en una lista para que no se repitan, de antemano gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No he entendido si necesitas guardar un código de caracteres aleatorios sin que se repitan entre sí los caracteres.

O si lo que quieres es obtener varios códigos, y que no se repitan los códigos entre si.

Te pongo las 2 opciones para conseguir un código aleatorio:

```
extension String {
  static func randomString(size: UInt) -> String {
    let stringSet = "0123456789aAbBcCdDeEfFgGhHiIjJkKlLmMnNoOpPqQrRsStTuUvVwWxXyYzZ"

    var randomString = ""
    for _ in 0..<size {
        let randomIndex = arc4random_uniform(UInt32(stringSet.count))
        let charIndex = stringSet.index(stringSet.startIndex, offsetBy: Int(randomIndex))
        randomString.append(String(stringSet[charIndex]))
    }
    return randomString
  }

  static func randomUniqueCharsString(size: UInt) -> String {
    var stringSet = "0123456789aAbBcCdDeEfFgGhHiIjJkKlLmMnNoOpPqQrRsStTuUvVwWxXyYzZ"

    let maxPossibleSize = [size, UInt(stringSet.count)].min()!

    var randomString = ""
    for _ in 0..<maxPossibleSize {
        let randomIndex = arc4random_uniform(UInt32(stringSet.count))
        let charIndex = stringSet.index(stringSet.startIndex, offsetBy: Int(randomIndex))
        let newChar = stringSet[charIndex]
        stringSet.remove(at: charIndex)
        randomString.append(newChar)
    }
    return randomString
  }
}
```

Y así podrías obtener un listado con valores únicos (usando ambas funciones):

```
var codes: Set<String> = Set()
var uniqueCharCodes: Set<String> = Set()

let totalCodes = 5
let codesSize: UInt = 10

while codes.count < totalCodes {
   codes.insert(String.randomString(size: codesSize))
}

while uniqueCharCodes.count < totalCodes {
   uniqueCharCodes.insert(String.randomUniqueCharsString(size: codesSize))
}

print(codes)
print(uniqueCharCodes)
```

Comment: Muy buena, me la apunto por si un día necesito este código :)

Answer (score 0):

> O si lo que quieres es obtener varios códigos, y que no se repitan los códigos entre si.ta en bloque

Exactamente eso es lo que buscaba muchas gracias